# How do I read in lines of a text file when the line breaks are "/r" instead of "/n"?

Tags: ocaml, text-files, line-breaks

I have a massive .txt file with a list of tens of thousands of adjectives. In the text files, each word is on its own line. I read it into a list (that I then put into an array using `Array.of_list`) with the following function:

```
let read_file filename = 
    let lines = ref [] in
    let chan = open_in filename in
      try
        while true; do
      lines := input_line chan :: !lines
        done; []
      with End_of_file ->
        close_in chan;
        List.rev !lines ;;
```

But it's not working because the line breaks are being represented with `/r` and not `/n`. I end up with a list with one element that basically looks like this: `["abacinate\rabandon\rabase\rabash\rabate\rabbreviate\rabdicate"]`

What is the best way to change the line breaks from `/r` to `/n`? Or is there a way to read in the text file so that I can tell it to make a new element in the list when it gets to `/r`?

Comment: I've now realized that this was a very stupid question. I just used find and replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could certainly play around with doing some sort of substitution with a regex in OCaml... For example, you could read in the whole file into a string and do the substitution.  However, if your textfile doesn't change (and I'm guessing that it doesn't in this case as it's just a big list of adjectives) I would use my text editor's search and replace facilities to do the replace in the textfile itself, as opposed to trying to do it in your OCaml program.

If you have dos2unix installed you could use that to do the translation. You could also use something like this:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r/\n/' filename
```

...using this approach means you change the file once and you're done with it as opposed to always doing the substitution in your program which will take a little bit of extra time every time you run the program.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, if your file has `\r`-separated records and not `\n`-separated records, it's not a text files made of lines. It's a file in some other format, which happens to be the text format of some other platform. So [converting the file to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783419/how-do-i-read-in-lines-of-a-text-file-when-the-line-breaks-are-r-instead-of/5783772#5783772) is the obvious solution.

If you need your program to cope with newlines, you'll have to write a replacement to `input_line`, because it has the native notion of line built-in (i.e. `LF` on unix, `CR` on MacOS before OSX, `CR LF` on DOS and Windows).

Since you're reading the whole file into memory anyway, you can read it all in a `Buffer`. Note that `Buffer.add_channel` won't work unless you know the file size in advance (and then you might as well read it into a string). Untested:

```
let input_until_eof (chan : in_channel) : string =
  let buf = Buffer.create 10000 and tmp = String.create 4096 and n = ref 0 in
  while n := input chan tmp 0 (String.length tmp); n <> 0 do
    Buffer.add_substring buf tmp
  done;
  Buffer.contents buf
let tolerant_newline_regexp = Str.regexp "\r\\|\n\\|\013\|\010\013?"
let input_all_lines chan : string list =
  Str.split tolerant_newline_regexp (input_until_eof chan)
```

If you're going to do further parsing on the file contents, use the `Stream` module or Ocamllex.